# Email address validation error

Tags: column, validation

I have an EMAIL column and added this validation code:

```
=AND(
 ISERROR(FIND(" ", [EMAIL],1)),
 IF(ISERROR(FIND("@", [EMAIL],2)),
  FALSE,
  AND(
   ISERROR(FIND("@",[EMAIL], FIND("@", [EMAIL],2)+1)),
   IF(ISERROR(FIND(".", [EMAIL], FIND("@", [EMAIL],2)+2)),
    FALSE,
    FIND(".", [EMAIL], FIND("@", [EMAIL],2)+2) < LEN([EMAIL])
   )
  )
 )
)
```

as suggested here :

[Validate Email Address Columns in SharePoint](http://thechriskent.com/2012/08/16/validate-email-address-columns-in-sharepoint/)

Unfortunately I get an error message

> The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported - See more at:
>   http://sharepointknowledgebase.blogspot.it/2011/02/formula-contains-syntax-error-or-is-not.html#.VL5KwXl8OUk

Comment: Perhaps check the naming of the colums. It should be EMAIL all on uppercase.

Comment: Thanks but column name is EMAIL uppercase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably this error occurs since locale for web site is set to non-default language (1033) and the *incorrect* delimiter is specified for a function (in your case the delimiter is `,`) *The delimiter in formula is language dependent*.

For example when `web locale` is set to `1035 (Finnish)` then the proper syntax for formula is:

```
=AND(ISERROR(FIND(" ";Email;1));IF(ISERROR(FIND("@";Email;2));FALSE;AND(ISERROR(FIND("@";Email;FIND("@";Email;2)+1));IF(ISERROR(FIND(".";Email;FIND("@";Email;2)+2));FALSE;FIND(".";Email;FIND("@";Email;2)+2)<LEN(Email)))))
```

> Note: delimiter `;` is used instead of `,`

**Solution**

- Determine the web locale  (go to `Site Settings` -> click `Regional settings` under `Site Administration` group and find `Locale` for the current web site)
- Make sure the proper syntax for the specified locale is used (use the below links)

---

You could also consider another approach (more advanced i would say) to validate email field as explained in [this article](http://blog.vgrem.com/2014/03/14/introduction-to-client-forms-validation-in-sharepoint-2013/). The idea is to apply client-side validation for a text field using regular expression.

### References

- [Overview of formulas and functions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/CH011711541033.aspx)
- [A list of available functions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/CH011711171033.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following JS.

```
    function IsValidEmail(Email) {

        var expr = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;

        return expr.test(Email);

    };

    function ValidateEmails() {

        var message = ""

        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

            if (inputs[i].type == "text" && inputs[i].className.indexOf("Email") != -1) {

                var email = inputs[i].value;

                if (IsValidEmail(Email)) {

                    message += @ + " - Valid Email.\n"

                } else {

                    message += @gmail + " - Invalid Email.\n"
                    message += @yahoo + " - Invalid Email.\n"

                }

            }

        }

        alert(invalid email address);

    }
```